# Rally - Create filter based on Drop Down (Multi-Value) custom field

Tags: rally

Rally - Create filter based on Drop Down (Multi-Value) custom field

We have created a Drop Down (Multi-Value) custom field for releases in Rally. It could have two fields basically,

Field1
Field2

How can we add a filter to select all release records that have Field1 selected? or may be Field1 and Field2 both(using Rally SDK).

e.g. we created a store as follows:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store',{
    model: 'Release',
    fetch: ['Name','ReleaseDate','ReleaseStartDate', 'Project', 'c_SomeCustomField'],
    filters: {property: 'c_SomeCustomField', value:'Field1'},// this we need to achieve

});
```

where 'c_SomeCustomField' is a Drop Down (Multi-Value) custom field. We need to add filter based on 'c_SomeCustomField' to select all the release records which are having Field1 as a value? or may be Field1 and Field2 both as a value.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved using filters: {property: 'c_SomeCustomField', operator: 'contains', value:'Field1'},

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that either on the Timeboxes page for releases or by adding a Custom List app set to Release on your dashboard or a custom page.

If you want to filter by both values at the same time, just create and advanced filter with two conditions for your custom field, OR'ed together.  Here is an example screenshot (in this case the multivalue custom field is called Repos Affected):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyle. Sorry I missed to mention, we want to achieve this using Rally SDK.

Comment: ah, ok.  well, that filtering component above is available in the sdk.  or you can also use FieldValueComboBox i think: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox

if that's not enough to get started, can you edit your question to include a little more info about what you're trying to build?